# Difference between "there exists at most one" and "there exists only one"

Tags: logic, notation, quantifiers

What is the difference in proof of this type?
I know that for "there exists only one" existence
and uniqueness must be demonstrated but for
"there exists at most one" I don't understand very well.

Comment: there could exist none; then "there exists at most one" would be true but "there exists only one" would not

Comment: "there exists only one"  means "there exists (exactly) one". Whereas "there exists at most one" means either "there exists (exactly) one" or "there exists (exactly) none". So the statement, "there exists at most one integer between $0.5$ and $0.6$" is True, whereas the statement, "there exists only one integer between $0.5$ and $0.6$" is False.

Comment: @AdamRubinson That should be an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"there exists only one"  means "there exists (exactly) one". Whereas "there exists at most one" means either "there exists (exactly) one" or "there exists (exactly) none". So the statement, "there exists at most one integer between $0.5$ and $0.6$" is True, whereas the statement, "there exists only one integer between $0.5$ and $0.6$" is False.